# Counter in range() not recognized as integer

Tags: python, types, pycharm, warnings

I am trying to step through a list of lists operating on each element of each list using nested for loops.  I am getting a warning from PyCharm that the type of the counter in the second for loop is not certain to be an integer, despite it is derived from a range value. The code executes correctly, by why the warning?

```
def get_vote_fraction(cl_count, ag_vector):
    v_f_vector = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
    for b in range(0, len(v_f_vector)):
        for c in range(0, len(v_f_vector[b])):
            v_f_vector[b][c] = f"{(ag_vector[b][c] / cl_count): .2F}"
    return v_f_vector


aggregated_vector = [[0, 8, 0, 6], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0], [0, 0, 10, 0], [0, 10, 0, 0, 0]]
class_count = 10
vote_fraction = get_vote_fraction(class_count, aggregated_vector)
print(vote_fraction)
```

As expected the output is [[' 0.00', ' 0.80', ' 0.00', ' 0.60'], [' 0.00', ' 0.10', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.90', ' 0.00'], [' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 1.00', ' 0.00'], [' 0.00', ' 1.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00']]

I get a warning that c in v_f_vector[b][c] can be of Unexpected type(s) (int, str) which says c is not sufficiently defined as an integer.  I hesitate to raise an issue with PyCharm since I may be missing something simple. Anyone see what I am missing?

Comment: `c` (your range variable) will indeed be an integer; if i see it right, the complaint is about `v_f_vector[b][c]` (the list element).

Comment: You can create a ticket. It is pretty common that Pycharm cannot resolve this kind of things from my experience. Just know that you can make the warning become a weak warning in your settings if it bothers you.

Comment: There was no warning for me when I tested this

Answer (score 2):

**Regarding the *PyCharm* warning** (that the question is all about)

Although the 2<sup>nd</sup> index (***c***) is highlighted, making users think **it** is the problem, **it's not about that, at all**.

Generally, lists are *homogeneous* containers, meaning that they contain elements of the same type. 
*PyCharm* evaluated ***v_f_vector*** as being **a list of lists of *int*s** (and thus `v_f_vector[b][c]` as an ***int***). Trying to assign a **string** to it, would kind of break the list homogeneity, hence the warning. 
Try assigning dummy values (e.g. `0.01f`, `()`, **`[]`**, ...) to it, and the warning text will change, like in the image below:

[image: Img0]

As a quick (and dirty) workaround, if the lists are going to contain strings, you could do something like:

```py
v_f_vector = [["", "", "", ""], ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""], ["", "", "", ""], ["", "", "", "", ""]]
```

**Regarding the code that lead to this**

Declaring a list with a certain content, and then coming back and changing that content (based on another (similar structural) list) is counter-intuitive.

Your (end) goal, can be achieved in **one** line of code (the most *Python*ic form), consisting of a *list comprehension* (check [[Python 3.Docs]: List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)). Since your list nesting level is 2, so will be the comprehension:

> ```py
> >>> aggregated_vector = [[0, 8, 0, 6], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0], [0, 0, 10, 0], [0, 10, 0, 0, 0]]
> >>> class_count = 10
> >>>
> >>> vote_fraction = [[f"{(item1 / class_count): .2F}" for item1 in item0] for item0 in aggregated_vector]
> >>> print(vote_fraction)
> [[' 0.00', ' 0.80', ' 0.00', ' 0.60'], [' 0.00', ' 0.10', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.90', ' 0.00'], [' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 1.00', ' 0.00'], [' 0.00', ' 1.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00']]
> >>>
> >>> # Or, if you REALLY need to have a function
> ...
> >>> def get_vote_fraction(cl_count, ag_vector):
> ...     return [[f"{(item1 / cl_count): .2F}" for item1 in item0] for item0 in ag_vector]
> ...
> >>>
> >>> print(get_vote_fraction(class_count, aggregated_vector))
> [[' 0.00', ' 0.80', ' 0.00', ' 0.60'], [' 0.00', ' 0.10', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.90', ' 0.00'], [' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 1.00', ' 0.00'], [' 0.00', ' 1.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00', ' 0.00']]
> ```

**Note**: your code could be adapted as well, but I'd suggest to go with the recommended variant(s).

Answer (score 1):

I think that the warning comes from the fact that you are replacing integer values with strings. When I tried to instanciate `v_f_vector` with `'0'` instead of `0`, PyCharm didn't show any warning:

```
v_f_vector = [['0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0']]
```

However, it may be not the best way to fix the problem. I would suggest such a refactoring of your code:

```
def get_vote_fraction(cl_count, ag_vector):
    v_f_vector = []
    for b in range(0, len(ag_vector)):
        v_f_vector.append([])
        for c in range(0, len(ag_vector[b])):
            v_f_vector[b].append(f"{(ag_vector[b][c] / cl_count): .2F}")
    return v_f_vector


aggregated_vector = [[0, 8, 0, 6], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0], [0, 0, 10, 0], [0, 10, 0, 0, 0]]
class_count = 10
vote_fraction = get_vote_fraction(class_count, aggregated_vector)
print(vote_fraction)
```

It will allow you to change `aggregated_vector` without reflecting these changes to instanciated `v_f_vector`.

Comment: Thank you for the clearest answer to my question. I am aware of options like enumerate and list comprehensions! The snippet of code i provided was the simplest I could devise that created the warning situation, which is indeed exactly as you described. (I also like your refactoring suggestion!)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `enumerate()`

Example:

```
iterable = [1,2,3,4]
for i, v in enumerate(iterable):
    print(i,v)
```

Expected output

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

Instead of

```
for x in range(0, len(iterable)):
    print(x, iterable[x])
```

Sorry this isn't really an answer to your question, but it's for more readable this way, also, enumerate will always give you an index and a value, or if it was a dictionary then the key and the value.

It might also be worth noting it makes far more human readable sense to nest lists in a dictionary and then give each of them a specific key so that you can access them.

Just food for thought

To add clarity, let's say you have 4 vectors, vectors a, b, x and y. You could have each of their respective lists in their own dictionary key, then access them with their key.

Comment: If you understand this is not really an answer, why not adding a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: Because it's awful practice to use a range in len of an iterable. A comment cannot explain that as well as I have done with  an example.